# Don't really understand the notation

Tags: logic, big-o, theory, notation

I don't really understand how or what I'm supposed to prove. I've researched into each, but still unclear to me what is expected.

> Which of the following statements are true? Prove your answers.
>
> 1. n² ∈ O(n³)
> 2. n² ∈ Ω(n³)
> 3. 2ⁿ ∈ Θ(2<sup>n+1</sup>)
> 4. n! ∈ Θ((n+1)!)

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Presumably, you have a teacher or at least some material explaining big-oh notation, and weren't given this assignment with no context.

Comment: I understand big-oh notation but I don't understand how to prove that n^2 exists in O(n^3)

Comment: As I understand this, you just have to say for each statement "true" or "false" and prove that your answer is right.

Comment: I just don't know where I can find the resources to prove whether they are true or false

Comment: How about starting by reading the wikipedia article about [Big O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation)

Answer (score 0):

Since this (probably homework) questions is some days old, I think I can answer this question in short.

The wikipedia page (and hopefully your textbook and/or notes too) says

```
f(n) ∈ O(g(n))     ⇔     lim sup |f(n)/g(n)| < ∞
f(n) ∈ Ω(g(n))     ⇔     lim sup |f(n)/g(n)| > 0
f(n) ∈ Θ(g(n))     ⇔     f(n) ∈ O(g(n)) and f(n) ∈ Ω(g(n))
```

To prove the left side you can prove the right side.

1. `n² ∈ O(n³)` is true, due to

   ```
   lim sup |n²/n³| = lim (n²/n³) = lim (1/n) = 0 < ∞
   ```
2. `n² ∈ Ω(n³)` is false, due to

   ```
   lim sup |n²/n³| = lim (n²/n³) = lim (1/n) = 0
   ```
3. `2ⁿ ∈ Θ(2n+1)` is true, due to

   ```
   0 < lim sup |2ⁿ/2<sup>n+1</sup>| = lim (2ⁿ/(2⋅2ⁿ) = lim (1/2) = 1/2 < ∞
   ```
4. `n! ∈ Θ((n+1)!)` is false, due to

   ```
   lim sup |n!/(n+1)!| = lim (n!/((n+1)⋅n!) = lim (1/(n+1)) = 0
   ```

Notice: All limits holds for `n → ∞`.